# Youtube script has stopped working on search order

Tags: bash, youtube

Each night at midnight Ottawa Canada time I upload a video to my youtube channel via a script.

An hour or do later I have been using a script to get the Video ID of the last video uploaded and it creates a iframe file to upload to my web server.  This has stopped working after a number of years

Because I am not a programmer and it was so long ago that I set this up I don't know where to start.  I did look at the YouTube API web page and the console but could not find anything.  I know that running the script does not return the "videoid" like it has for the past few years.

```
'''
url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCOUnH8qVLmUe_2mmupWzEmQ&maxResults=1&key=DEVELOPERS KEY"

lastVideoId=$(curl -s "$url" | grep videoId | awk -F'[""]' '{print $4}')

'''
```

Out come would be to get The last videoid is saved as the variable $lastVideoId

Comment: What do you get when you call up the URL directly in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution without googleapis and the need of an apikey. It used the rss feed of your channel and return the first videoid it found.

```
# Define RSS feed for your channel
URL="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCOUnH8qVLmUe_2mmupWzEmQ"
videoid=$(curl -s $URL | grep "/watch?v=" | head -1 | sed "s/.*\?v=\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/g")
echo $videoid
```

explanation:

```
curl -s $URL         # get rss feed (curl in silent mode)
|                    # pipe output to...
grep "/watch?v="     # get only video urls
|                    # pipe output to...
head -1              # take first line with url
|                    # pipe output to...
sed "s/              # sed in substitution mode
\?v=                 # search '?v=' in url
\([^\"]*\)\"         # put everything up to next " in arg1 (\1)
.*                   # ignore rest of the line
/\1                  # print only arg1 
/g                   # global on the whole line
```